# TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to run this code:

```
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, initial_state=initial_state, sequence_length=real_length)

tensor_shape = outputs.get_shape()
for step_index in range(tensor_shape[0]):
    word_index = self.x[:, step_index]
    word_index = tf.reshape(word_index, [-1,1])
    index_weight = tf.gather(word_weight, word_index)
    outputs[step_index,  :,  :]=tf.mul(outputs[step_index,  :,  :] , index_weight)
```

But I get error on last line: 
`TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment`
It seems I can not assign to tensor, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In general, a TensorFlow tensor object is not assignable, so you cannot use it on the left-hand side of an assignment.

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do is to build a Python list of tensors, and [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) them together at the end of the loop:

```
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, initial_state=initial_state,
                          sequence_length=real_length)

output_list = []

tensor_shape = outputs.get_shape()
for step_index in range(tensor_shape[0]):
    word_index = self.x[:, step_index]
    word_index = tf.reshape(word_index, [-1,1])
    index_weight = tf.gather(word_weight, word_index)
    output_list.append(tf.mul(outputs[step_index, :, :] , index_weight))

outputs = tf.stack(output_list)
```

---

* With the exception of [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) objects, using the `Variable.assign()` etc. methods. However, `rnn.rnn()` likely returns a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) object that does not support this method.

Comment: Note that `tf.pack()` has been replaced by [tf.stack()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) since TensorFlow 1.0.

Comment: I have the same problem with the issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871023/how-do-i-assign-a-value-to-a-tensor-in-order-to-prevent-this-error-typeerror, but I do not know how can I do this with tf.stack. could please guide about this issue?

Comment: How would one do this?:
for x in range(int(r.shape[2]/2)):
    for d in range(1,int(r.shape[0]/2)):
      r[d, :, x, :] = r[0, :, x+d, :]

Answer (score 19):

Another way you can do it is like this.

```
aa=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(3, tf.int32))
aa=aa[2].assign(1)
```

then the output is:

```
array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

ref:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when trying to implement it this way:

`x = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,2,2,3], tf.float32))`
`x = x[:,:,:,1].assign(2.0)`

`with tf.Session() as sess:`
   `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`
   `x_data = sess.run(x)`

Comment: note: tf.Variable maintains its value across session runs, this is not always the right solution.

Comment: This answer has the worst performance in all speed tests I've done to assign 1D vectors to 2D array. Don't use this method! The fastest so far is mrry's answer with appending to a list and stacking.

Comment: doesn't work in TF2: EagerTensor object has no attribute 'assign'

Answer (score 8):

When you have a tensor already,
convert the tensor to a list using [tf.unstack](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) (TF2.0) and then use tf.stack like @mrry has mentioned. (when using a multi-dimensional tensor, be aware of the axis argument in unstack)

```
a_list = tf.unstack(a_tensor)

a_list[50:55] = [np.nan for i in range(6)]

a_tensor = tf.stack(a_list)
```

Comment: this worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Neither `tf.Tensor` nor `tf.Variable` is element-wise-assignable.
   There is a trick however which is not the most efficient way of
   course, especially when you do it iteratively.

   You can create a `mask` and a `new_layer` tensor with new values and
   then

   do a Hadamard product (element-wise product).

   ```
   x = original * mask + new_layer * (1-mask)
   ```

   The `original * mask` part sets the specified values of `original`
   to 0 and the second part, `new_layer*(1-mask)` assigns `new_layer`
   tensor whatever you want without modifying the elements assigned to
   0 by the `mask` tensor in the previous step.
2. Another way is to use numpy instead:

   ```
   x = np.zeros((tensor dimensions))
   ```
3. Use Pytorch:

   ```
   x = torch.zeros((tensor dimensions))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14132#issuecomment-483002522) says, a workaround would be to create a **NEW** tensor with the previous one and a new one on the zones needed.

1. Create a mask of shape `outputs` with 0's on the indices you want to replace and 1's elsewhere (Can work also with `True` and `False`)
2. Create new matrix of shape `outputs` with the new desired value: `new_values`
3. Replace only the needed indexes with: `outputs_new = outputs* mask + new_values * (1 - mask)`

If you would provide me with an MWE I could do the code for you.

A good reference is this note: [How to Replace Values by Index in a Tensor with TensorFlow-2.0](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-replace-values-by-index-in-a-tensor-with-tensorflow-2-0-510994fe6c5f)

Comment: How would one do this?
for x in range(int(r.shape[2]/2)):
    for d in range(1,int(r.shape[0]/2)):
      r[d, :, x, :] = r[0, :, x+d, :]