# Tensorflow - Choose TFRecord Features at Graph Build Tim

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have TFRecord Examples with the following feature mapping:

```
feature_mapping =  {
"sentence":tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string), 
'caps':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
'tags':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
'labels': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string)
}
```

I always need `sentence` and `labels`, but sometimes I want 0,1, or more of the remaining features.  I know what features I want at Graph build time.

How can I choose multiple features at graph build time?

For instance, sentence and labels, no problem:

```
parsed = tf.parse_example(example, features=feature_mapping)
sentence = parsed['sentence']
labels = parsed['labels']
```

But can I pull out multiple features? I.e.:

```
FEATURE_NAMES = ['caps', 'tags']
parsed = tf.parse_example(example, features=feature_mapping)
features = tf.multiple_features(parsed, FEATURE_NAMES] # Does something like this exist?
```

I'm willing to change my TFRecord representation as well.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a Python dictionary, right? So you could do something like `[parsed[k] for k in FEATURE_NAMES]` to get a list.

Comment: Yes, but  will that work for the graph representation?  I've been avoiding loops completely in TF.

Comment: Unless there are hundreds of these you're collecting, I wouldn't worry about it. And if there are, you'd need to concatenate some columns rather than changing the way they get looked up in that dictionary to make a performance difference..

Comment: Thanks @AllenLavoie, You were correct. I posted the correct code.  I guess the graph representation still confuses me sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Allen Lavoie for pointing out that it's a simple solution.  I needed to put them in a list, and then according to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow), I just needed to tf.pack into a list.  Below is the solution.

```
# get features
FEATURES = ['labels', 'caps']
output_list = [] 
for f in range(len(FEATURES)):
    feats = parsed[FEATURES[f]]
    dense_feats = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(feats, default_value='<PAD>')
    output_list.append(dense_feats)

features = tf.pack(output_list)
```