# TensorFlow: construct a tensor with recursively defined elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to do something like:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.ones([100], dtype=tf.float32))
x0 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1], dtype=tf.float32))
def f(x):
    return tf.sin(x)
x[0] = x0
for i in range(1,100):
    x[i+1] = f(x[i])
```

to construct a tensor 'x'. Is such a construct possible? I looked at 'tf.while_loop' but does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f(x):
    return tf.sin(x)
x = []
x.append(tf.constant(1.0))
for i in range(1,100):
    x.append(f(i))
```

Is this what you want?
This is not recursive by the way. It's iterative.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I would like to get out a tensor 'x'. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: See this, maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow

Comment: The method in the link gives me what I want, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow) pretty much solves the problem as Atirag pointed out, but 'tf.pack()' seems to have been deprecated. Just for completeness, here is an up-to-date solution to the posted problem:

```
x0 = tf.Variable(tf.ones(1, dtype=tf.float32))
def f(x):
    return tf.sin(x)
x = [x0]
for i in range(1, 100):
    x.append(f(x[i - 1]))

tf.stack(x)
```