# Assigning values from 12 channel small image to 3 channel large image tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 12 channel small image whose values have to be assigned to a 3 channel large (Please find the code below).

Height of large image= Height of small image*2

Width of large image= width of small image*2

I have written a function in numpy library which works fine for me. I want to know how i can implement the same with tensorflow. Also would like to know if there are api's which does the same job as my function in tensorflow.

```
def reconstruct_image(image):
    image=np.array(image)
    M=image.shape[0]
    N=image.shape[1]
    img = np.zeros((M* 2, N* 2,3))

    # For red channel
    img[0:2*M:2,0:2*N:2,0]=image[:,:,0]
    img[0:2*M:2,1:2*N:2,0]=image[:,:,1]
    img[1:2*M:2,0:2*N:2,0]=image[:,:,2]
    img[1:2*M:2,1:2*N:2,0]=image[:,:,3]
    #For green channel
    img[0:2*M:2, 0:2*N:2,1] = image[:,:,4]
    img[0:2*M:2, 1:2*N:2,1] = image[:,:,5]
    img[1:2*M:2, 0:2*N:2,1] = image[:,:,6]
    img[1:2*M:2, 1:2*N:2,1] = image[:,:,7]
    img[0:2*M:2, 0:2*N:2,2] = image[:,:,8]
    #For blue channel
    img[0:2*M:2, 1:2*N:2,2] = image[:,:,9]
    img[1:2*M:2, 0:2*N:2,2] = image[:,:,10]
    img[1:2*M:2, 1:2*N:2,2] = image[:,:,11]

    return img
```

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I edited my post. I don't know how to add four channel of small image to a single channel image in tensorflow. I think the ans which you have referred does not solve my problem. Please correct me if i am wrong.