# ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

My simple custom training is failing because I cannot manipulate the output from the model prior to computing the loss. It says I cannot do assigments to that tensor. How can I fix it ?

```
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred = model(inputs, training=True)
        pred = tf.roll(pred, shift=1, axis=1)
        pred[:, 0, :].assign(tf.zeros_like(pred[:, 0, :]))
        loss = loss_object(target, pred)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model_.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model_.trainable_variables))
```

> ```
> ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
> ```

And sometimes I get this error:

> ```
> TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow).

Comment: @giser_yugang That looks exactly like my problem, thanks.