# Conditional Replace for Custom Loss Function Constraint? TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I have a model that returns two values per sample in a batch where the first value must be >=0 and the second must be <=0. My first attempt at a custom error function follows:

```
def maxMinDiffLossConstrained(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
 
    y_pred_shape = list(y_pred.shape) # y_pred returns a tuple, we want a list so we can construct another tensor 
    #y_pred_data = y_pred.numpy() # get the tensor data as a numpy array 
        
    y_pred[y_pred[:,0] < 0, 0] = -10            
    y_pred[y_pred[:,1] > 0, 1] = 10            
        
    y_mod = tf.reshape(y_pred, y_pred_shape)   
   
    mse = MeanSquaredError()
    loss = mse(y_true, y_mod)

    return loss
```

Which is where I got the error

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

As you can see I tried using `y_pred.numpy()` but the object but `type(y_pred)` is `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>` and returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I have checked a number of other posts. This one suggests unstacking and restacking

[TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow)

This next longer article was helpful, it suggested decomposing based on conditions and then remaking the tensor. I am still working towards a solution with this approach:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-replace-values-by-index-in-a-tensor-with-tensorflow-2-0-510994fe6c5f

Unfortunately, since the dimensions of my Tensor are `(batch_size, 2)` I still have not figured out a solution that works. My difficulty is that, after I get the True/False vector for dim1 (>=0) and dim2 (<=0) with the following code:

```
maxes_to_remove = y_pred[:,0] < 0 
mins_to_remove = y_pred[:,1] > 0

idx_maxes = tf.where(maxes_to_remove == True)
idx_mins = tf.where(mins_to_remove == True)
```

I am not sure how to replace only the values in the 1st dimension that need to be replaced and only the values in the second that need to be replaced.

As a side note, i also ran into [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5916) but was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe tensors in tf are *immutable*, so you cannot assign values to indices in the array. Two workarounds:

1. Define a new tensor that is created using the original tensor and some additional operations. I recommend using `tf.keras.backend.switch()`, which allows you to assign values to a new tensor from one of two input tensors (which for you will be a tensor of -10 and a tensor of 10) based on the tensor of boolean values (for you this will be perhaps idx_maxes?)
2. Convert to numpy arrays, change as necessary, and convert back to tensor. **Note that this only works if you are in eager execution mode.** If you are in graph mode, intuitively converting to numpy is a no-go because numpy arrays do not support graph computation, so the chain of operations would be lost during conversion.

Comment: Converting to numpy arrays was my first attempt but I failed. I've seen eager tensors pop up but I've not figured out how they work. What is the difference and how do you switch modes?