# manipulate a matrix tensor flow, problem with tf.data.dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I want to concatenate three images with size [1024,1024,3] to make a batch with size [3,1024,1024,3]. I wrote this code with TensorFlow but it doesn't work. It returns the error `"InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(1024, 1024, 3), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it."`.

```
def decode_img(filename):
    image = tf.ones((3,1024,1024,3),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    cnt=0
    slices = []
    for fi in filename:
      bits = tf.io.read_file(fi)
      img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
      img = tf.image.resize(img, (1024,1024))
      slices.append(tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0)
      cnt +=1

    image = tf.stack(slices)
    return image

#-----------------------
filenames = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png']
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(decode_img, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
```

Comment: Also, repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697747/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-tensorflow#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20a%20TensorFlow%20tensor,hand%20side%20of%20an%20assignment.&text=Tensor%20object%20that%20does%20not%20support%20this%20method.

Answer (score 1):

In general, tensorflow does not support item assignment. Rather, generate all the `img` layers you want and then use `tf.stack()` or `tf.concatenate`.

```
filename = [img1.png, img2.png, img3.png]
cnt=0
slices = []
for fi in filename:
  bits = tf.io.read_file(fi)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (1024,1024))
  slices.append(tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0)
  cnt +=1

image = tf.stack(slices)
```

Comment: By this way, it returns error "InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(1024, 1024, 3), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it"

Comment: Actually, I am using the following code, it returns the error on line  "image = tf.stack(slices)"

def decode_img(filename):
 image = tf.ones((3,1024,1024,3),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
 cnt=0
 slices = []
 for fi in filename:
   bits = tf.io.read_file(fi)
   img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
   img = tf.image.resize(img, (1024,1024))
   slices.append(tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0)
   cnt +=1
 image = tf.stack(slices)
 return image

filenames = [img1.png, img2.png, img3.png]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(decode_img)

Comment: Post in question formatted as code, this is very hard to read

Comment: See, in your code you define image first, then try to assign a new value to image. Assignment is not allowed in general in tf. Every time you want to combine a few variables or modify them, you need to assign the result to a **new** variable. This is based on the way tensorflow defines its function graphs for efficient backpropogation I believe

Comment: sorry, that was a piece of my code, I edited the question and put the all of my code

Comment: remove this line: `image = tf.ones((3,1024,1024,3),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)`